# Filter out sentences in a list that don't contain particular words

Tags: list, python-2.7

Let's say I have this list:

```
sentences = ['the cat slept', 'the dog jumped', 'the bird flew']
```

I want to filter out any sentences that contain terms from the following list:

```
terms = ['clock', 'dog']
```

I should get:

```
['the cat slept', 'the bird flew']
```

I tried this solution, but it doesn't work

```
empty = []
if any(x not in terms for x in sentences):
    empty.append(x)
```

What's the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a solution like this for readability rather than reducing to a one liner:

```
for sentence in sentences:
    if all(term not in sentence for term in terms):
        empty.append(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple brute-force O(m*n) approach using list comprehension:

For each sentence - check if any of not allowed terms are found in this sentence and allow sentence if there was no match.

```
[s for s in sentences if not any(t in s for t in terms)]
# ['the cat slept', 'the bird flew']
```

Obviously, you can also invert condition and to something like:

```
[s for s in sentences if all(t not in s for t in terms)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the above two answers but using filter, perhaps being closer to the problem specification:

```
filter(lambda x: all([el not in terms for el in x.split(' ')]), sentences)
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary Seach is more optimized for too long sentences and terms.

```
from bisect import bisect
def binary_search(a,x,lo=0,hi=-1):
    i = bisect(a,x,lo,hi)
    if i == 0:
       return -1
    elif a[i-1] == x:
       return i-1
    else:
      return -1



sentences = ['the cat slept', 'the dog jumped', 'the bird flew', 'the a']
terms = ['clock', 'dog']

sentences_with_sorted = [(sentence, sorted(sentence.split()))
                     for sentence in sentences] # sort them for binary search


valid_sentences = []
for sentence in sentences_with_sorted:

       list_of_word = sentence[1] # get sorted word list

       if all([1 if binary_search(list_of_word, word)<0 else 0
        for word in terms]): # find no word found

           valid_sentences.append(sentence[0]) # append them

print valid_sentences
```